# Decoding invalid JSON with cjson - python-django

Tags: python, django, json

A Google API I'm using is outputting invalid JSON for the '&' sign.

**"name" : "Abercrombie \x26 Fitch Co."**

I've tired simply .replace('\x26', '&'), but that hasn't fixed the issue in python-django.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: It would be nice to see the JSON output, or at least the wrong part ;)

Comment: "name" : "Abercrombie \x26 Fitch Co."

Comment: '\x26' is '&' so your replacement won't do anything even if it does match '\x26'.

Comment: There's nothing invalid about that JSON.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: '\xXX' is not a valid JSON escaping. Standard define only '\uXXXX' escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed `{ }`, I can decode it properly. Are you using `UTF-8` in your python interpreter?

```
In [11]: simplejson.loads('''{"name" : "Abercrombie \x26 Fitch Co."}''')
Out[11]: {'name': 'Abercrombie & Fitch Co.'}
```